why java virtual threads use forkjoinpool
Why is the default scheduler for virtual threads in jdk21 forkjoinpool instead of ThreadPoolExecutor?
The reason I can think of is because in a fork join pool, it is possible to ensure that even if a virtual thread is rebound to a platform thread, it can be bound to the original platform thread, because the fork join pool has an array of workqueues, a task is in a workqueue, and a workqueue corresponds to a platform thread. thread, but this is without considering task stealing, so what else is the reason?
I've noticed that there is no method in jdk21 that enables the user to set the scheduler for virtual threads, as ThreadBuilders are private and the scheduler parameter is not passed in the public ofVirtual method, is this because the scheduler for virtual threads only supports forkjoinpool at the moment?

Add a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example to your question.

The article at https://blogs.oracle.com/javamagazine/post/going-inside-javas-project-loom-and-virtual-threads says that the work stealing aspect is the reason why a ForkJoinPool was selected.

No, I don't think that "rebounding to the original platform thread" (did you mean Carrier of a virtual thread?) is what ForkJoinPool is doing (and what would be a benefit of it?). ForkJoinPool is just most advanced concurrent ExecutorService JDK has. In comparison to older 1.5 ThreadPoolExecutor, which uses older AQS-based technique, FJP uses "jdk-internal Unsafe for atomics and special memory modes", which presumably more efficient "in very racy code".

@igor.zh
Do you mean that ThreadPoolExecutor performs worse in multithreading compared to FJP? Is ThreadPoolExecutor obsolete compared to FJP?

Yes, I do believe so. First, a well-known fact, because of work-stealing,  Second, less-known fact, because of usage of VarHandle/Unsafe, FJP does not use the first one, but many newer classes in Java Concurrency do.  ThreadPoolExecutor is, of course, good old pool and will work perfectly in not so demanding and "less racy" conditions. BTW, I was able to use ThreadPoolExecutor as a pool for virtual threads; I can post the code here if you are interested,

@igor.zh it’s a tenacious myth that Unsafe was faster than alternatives, just because there’s “unsafe” in its name. You may read this article, especially this part of it. That “work-stealing” is an over-hyped feature too. In ordinary thread pool implementations, threads will also pick up any task, if one is available. Since they have no local queue, there isn’t even a need to “steal” a job from another thread to get this done.

I know, @Holger, I know :) . Moreover, recently I implemented my own very simple
SynchronousQueue , based on ReentrantLock and Conditions, compared the performance of both stock and mine versions and was surprised not finding significant difference. But look how FJP is treated now in Java, look how all synchronizers now implement ForkJoinPool.ManagedBlocker. In that sense I believe FJP is still a way to go. And second thing: can we be sure that Unsafing is not faster in "very racy" condition?  Shipilev's blog is more like an open issue, more like: "Unsafe is not always faster".

As for FJP being overhyped - it is pretty obvious. We, however, have an unanswered thread that questions whether the work-stealing in FJP actually happens in these notorious "very racy" conditions and how often.

@igor.zh   Yes, I'm very curious how I can use ThreadPoolExecutor as a scheduler for virtual threads, can you show the code, thanks a lot!

Not knowing the stack you are using I posted very generic Executor implementation. Hopefully it could be used with any stack. A solution for Spring Boot + Tomcat is available, and I can post it too if needed. Or else let me know your stack.

@igor.zh yes ofcourse,I use spring Boot +tomcat ,Thank you very much for the code!

Please check out the update. Later on I provide a link to a sample project in github.

@igor.zh no, Shiplev’s article addressed the open issues up to the point that after solving them, the only expensive operation left was the Unsafe operation itself, which happens in either case, as the public API uses the same Unsafe under the hood. Besides that, the term “work-stealing” is questionable in the context of the virtual thread scheduler which does not create F/J Tasks but uses it like any other Executor. Every virtual thread is “stolen”…

According to a request of the OP to configure VirtualThread with a custom thread pool, the following solution is discussed below.
As of JDK 21 there is no way to set up a custom Executor/scheduler for  VirtualThread class: this class along with ThreadBuilders.VirtualThreadBuilder and VirtualThreadFactory are java.lang package-private and the only way to do so is to use Reflection.
public static Thread.Builder customVirtualThreadPool(Executor executor) throws ReflectiveOperationException {
    var ctor = Class.forName("java.lang.ThreadBuilders$VirtualThreadBuilder")
            .getDeclaredConstructor(Executor.class);
    ctor.setAccessible(true);
    return (Thread.Builder) ctor.newInstance(executor);
}

As access to java.lang classes is attempted it might be necessary to explicitly allow it in application parameters
--add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED

as Module java.base does not "opens java.lang" thread suggests.
Note that this can be used to set up custom ForkJoinPool instance as an actual pool in order to get an access to work-stealing count.
For Spring Boot/Tomcat application further configuration does not differ from configuration of any other such Executor.
As usual, to run Tomcat worker threads on this Excecutor, the ones that executes @Controllers methods, annotated with @RequestMapping and analogous, customize Tomcat Protocol Handler:
@Bean
public TomcatProtocolHandlerCustomizer<?> protocolHandlerVirtualThreadExecutorCustomizer() {
    return protocolHandler -> {
        try {
            protocolHandler.setExecutor(
                    customVirtualThreadPool(Executors.newCachedThreadPool())::start);
        } catch (ReflectiveOperationException e) {
            throw new BeanInitializationException("Cannot create custom Virtual Thread Executor", e);
        }
    };
}

Similarly, to run Spring-controlled asynchronous methods on this Executor, configuration will look like this:
@Configuration
@EnableAsync
public class AppConfig {

    @Bean
    public TaskExecutor taskExecutor()  {
        try {
            return new TaskExecutorAdapter(customVirtualThreadPool(Executors.newCachedThreadPool())::start);
        } catch (ReflectiveOperationException e) {
            throw new BeanInitializationException("Cannot create custom Virtual Thread Executor", e);
        }
    }

}

and the asynchronous method like this:
@Service
@Async // will use `taskExecutor` by default, if there are more than one in the app, then Bean name can be specified
public class AsyncService {

    public void doSomething() {
        ...
    }

}

Note that presence of spring.threads.virtual.enabled = true in application property file is not required in both cases.
The above is applicable to Spring Boot 3.2.0; be cautious with older Tomcats, they may or may not support the configuration above.

The crucial part is the reflective construction of the thread builder. There is no need to keep using Reflection after that. There’s also no point in catching all those subclasses of ReflectiveOperationException, to wrap them in a new ReflectiveOperationException. So you can simplify it to static Thread.Builder customVirtualThreadPool(Executor executor) throws ReflectiveOperationException { var ctor = Class.forName("java.lang.ThreadBuilders$VirtualThreadBuilder").getDeclaredConstructor(Executor.class); ctor.setAccessible(true); return (Thread.Builder)ctor.newInstance(executor); }

This static method can be used together with the public API, e.g. Executor e = customVirtualThreadPool(pool)::start; or Executors.newThreadPerTaskExecutor(customVirtualThreadPool(pool).factory()) or even applying more customization: Executors.newThreadPerTaskExecutor(customVirtualThreadPool(pool) .inheritInheritableThreadLocals(false).name("my-custom-thread-", 100).factory())

@Holger, completely agree, updated correspondingly to my best understanding. As for your comments on Unsafe ... need to think, too beefy of a topic. Not clear what you and Alexey offer. Everything in Java Concurrency is built upon Unsafe: either through AQS or ReentrantLock or VarHandle or directly. Alexey is of course a low-level expert, but we, people in the trench, are to do?

the takeaway is, since his suggested improvements were made, there is no reason left for developers to use Unsafe directly. The higher level APIs are at least on par. But it’s even possible that a future improvement will only accelerate the official API as Unsafe itself is the remaining bottleneck and the faster solution can only work without. Well, there are also practical advice you can read from his article, like storing a VarHandle in a static final field is a good idea to get maximum performance with today’s implementations.

@Holger. I see, indeed VarHandle doesn't use Unsafe directly, instead moving  essentials to native,  except few fencing methods. So my statement that VarHandle uses Unsafe under the hood, generally speaking, is not correct: maybe it does, but we cannot tell it from VarHandle code. But that means that Dr. Lea's comment to FJP at line   783, "use Unsafe for atomics and special memory modes rather than VarHandles" is in conflict with Alexey's blog?

Well, the optimized code of today is the legacy of tomorrow. The built-in classes have the advantage that they can get adapted with every Java version. If found this comment which suggests that the reason ForkJoinPool uses Unsafe in recent versions is not performance: “[…] should be using VarHandles. It was attempted for ForkJoinPool in JDK 19 but had to be reverted back to Unsafe due to bootstrapping and initialization issues…”

@Holger, yeah, definitely, Java changes at fast pace. Not very good idea, IMHO, to use legacy as a cornerstone of Java Concurrency, but I am aware of your skepticism of FJP. But coming back to work-stealing. I conducted some experiments with custom FJP as a VT pool and, indeed, like you said, every virtual thread is “stolen": steal count equals to number of VT creations. So, your point was that if there is no task split, there is no benefit in work-stealing?

The term “work-stealing” puts an emphasis on the wrong thing, as stealing is how all thread pools work. What sets F/J apart, is the existence of local queues in the first place, including the ability of a task to revoke a submission and execute the subtask locally, if it has not stolen yet. So you can create subtasks at a much higher granularity, to ensure saturation of worker threads even when tasks take significantly different time, without the overhead of a too large number of asynchronous tasks. A high steal count is not necessarily a good sign (but also not necessarily a bad sign).
